# How to center images for small mobile that were floated on desktop

Tags: image, css

I often float images either left or right around text on desktop but I want them centered for small mobile devices and the paragraph to drop below the image using Responsive design. I've got the paragraph dropping below the image using an online mobile viewing device but not when I try to view it via my computer. The image won't center online or on my computer.

Here is what I have found after many hours of research:

I have this set up for all images:

```
img{
   border:0;
   max-width:100%; 
   height:auto;
}
```

I have this set up for all paragraphs: it pushes the paragraph down below a floated image when the width of the paragraph is less than 10em (about 200 px).

```
p:before{
   content: "";
   width: 10em;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have applied the following for images to media queries less than 320 and max of 480:

```
img{
   max-width:100%;
   display:block!important; 
   margin:0 auto !important; 
   float:none !important; 
}
```

(i had to add !important to some of them or they wouldn't take but it's still not accepting margin: 0 auto; )

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you please post a working copy in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I've never used Jsfiddle before so I hope I did it right. It doesn't appear to be moving as anticipated in JS fiddle either, i.e., image isn't shrinking to 80% or centered, and paragraph doesn't drop below image under 480px mobile device.

    http://jsfiddle.net/Lorel509/ancpjmet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working update of what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/ancpjmet/3/

I changed `min-devide-width` to `min-width` and `max-devide-width` to `max-width` to be able to see the changes on my desktop browser in Google Chrome.

You have to set the `div` wrapping the `img` to `float: none;`, not the `img`:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {
    #image-wrapper{
        float: none !important;
    }
    #image-wrapper img{
        max-width: 80%;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }       
}
```

I also rebuild your `.clearfix` class to be more consistant and work in all browsers:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; }
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; }
```

Take a look at the changes in the jsfiddle given.

Comment: That worked except I can't use and ID because there are multiple images on the page. I set up new classes for floated images with padding on either left or right for the text:.imgfloatrpadl {float:right;
 padding-left:12px; }
 
.imgfloatlpadr {float:left;
 padding-right:12px; }

Comment: yes that will work too, I did not know the limitation you had for IDs in your website.

Comment: I guess you should mark the answer as your solution with the green check.

Comment: @Carolos Calla. Setting the float on the div instead of the image worked. Thanks.  I searched the site to find out how to vote as there are no green arrows showing on this page. I figured it out however.

Comment: Its ok man. When you give the green check just as you did you are marking the answer as the solution to your question. You also have the up arrow and down arrow that you give when you consider the answer was helpul (up arrow) or wrong, not helpful (down arrow). Enjoy the site :)